# extract values from json red node

Tags: json, node-red

```
"{"values":[{"key": "id", "value": 171},{"key": "counter", "value": 0},{"key": "temperature", "value": 2561},{"key": "x_axis", "value": -223},{"key": "y_axis", "value": -256},{"key": "z_axis", "value": 246},{"key": "battery", "value": 2817}]}"
```

I have a device (zolertia z1) sending in json data  using MQTT and I'm using a function in node-RED to extract values but i keep getting errors my code

```
return {values: msg.values.temperature};
```

error :

```
function : (error)
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'temperature' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from the MQTT node is a String not a JSON object.

[image]

Run the output through a JSON node to convert the string to a JSON object before passing it to your function node.

Also the object will be set as the `msg.payload.values` not `msg.values`

Comment: i added json but i keep getting the same error 
`code` "TypeError: Cannot read property 'temperature' of undefined"
i'm not sure from the code in the function...

Comment: You won't with that syntax, you will have to iterate over `msg.payload.values` array and check each `key` to see if it matches `temperature`